# C++ WIN API: When creating a child process using CreateProcess, do I need to make the input parameters have a global lifetime?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am really new to both C++ and Windows API. It suddenly comes to mind today whether I need to keep a long lifetime of the input parameters of `CreateProcess`. According MSDN:

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
  _Inout_opt_  LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
  _In_opt_     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
  _In_opt_     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_         BOOL bInheritHandles,
  _In_         DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  _In_opt_     LPVOID lpEnvironment,
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
  _In_         LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
  _Out_        LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
);
```

for instance, the `LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo` is pointer pointing to a STARTUPINFO structure.

I am wondering if I need to keep the structure alive after `CreateProcess` returns. In addition, in other Windows API functions, there are similar input parameters input as a pointer, I don't know if I need to keep those objects pointed by the input pointers alive after the API functions return.

I don't want to wait by using `WaitForSingleObject`, or at least not wait immediate after `CreateProcess`. `CreateProcess` is wrapped in my another function called 'ExecuteProcess'. After `CreateProcess` returns, `ExecuteProcess` also returns and all the input parameters defined on the stack will be destroyed when `ExecuteProcess` returns.

An example from MSDN [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to use `CreateProcess` in a similar way to me. `CreateProcess` is called in a function `CreateChildProcess` and all the input parameters are defined on the stack of 'CreateChildProcess' and `WaitForSingleObject` is not used either.

Answer (score 5):

No. The process arguments are copied into the new process's address space. You can get rid of them whenever you like.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule Win32 API functions will not take a reference to the variables that you pass as parameters. They might make copies, but will not take references. The reason being that were the function to take a reference to your variable and some how use it after the function returns, that imposes a very severe constraint on the caller. There may be exceptions to this general rule and if there are they will be clearly indicated in the documentation of the function.

What this means, in the context of your question, is that once `CreateProcess` returns, you are under no obligation to keep alive any of the variables that you passed to `CreateProcess`. The only obligation you have is that, if `CreateProcess` succeeds, you are now the owner of two handles, a process handle and a thread handle. You must, at some point, close those handles to avoid leaking them.

I've tried to answer this in a general way so that you can apply the same rule and reasoning to any other calls you make to Win32.

Comment: VG but I wouldn't say that's peculiar to Win32. Any system call I have ever used in over 40 years has had the same property.

Comment: @EJP I agree. I was not trying to single out Win32 particularly. Even broader than system APIs, no well designed API will routinely hold on the references to your variables.

Answer (score -1):

In general no, arguments are copied or inspected.

There is one special case with I think it was the command line argument, which needs to be writable for the Unicode version of the function.

Also there is some undocumented functionality where you may need to keep actual arguments around until the new process terminates, or at least until it has used the data. I do not recall exactly. But it's not a problem for normal use.

Comment: Thank you. But if I delete the memory of cmd line after CreateProcess returns, will the child process run properly?

Comment: @user3692418 Note: if you want to have wait-able handle(s) (not necessarily immediately, but perhaps later), you will likely want to keep the PI structure or at least copy the handles out. if you don't need them, then just close them, forget about PI, and move on. (+1 to the answer, btw).

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks. I will keep those output arguments alive but I am sure about those input arguments.

Comment: @user3692418: The information passed in the arguments is copied into the new process, so it will have a copy of the information and you need not worry about it. Usually in the MSDN documentation, when a resource is shared it will be said so explicitly, in which case it will almost always have to be allocated using `GlobalAlloc` or the likes.

Comment: @user3692418: Like said in the answer, if you don't need the handles that are returned in `PROCESS_INFORMATION` then close them immediately using `CloseHandle`, or else you'll 'leak' handles.

Comment: @MicroVirus `GlobalAlloc` and `LocalAlloc` are meaningless in Win32. They were provided only for Win16 backward-compatibility simply wrap the same heap allocation function (i.e. `VirtualAlloc`). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366596(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Maybe the downvote is for your uncited and unfounded "there is some undocumented functionality..." claim.

Comment: @AndrewMedico There are a couple of functions that, for legacy reasons, dictate you to allocate memory using `GlobalAlloc` (for instance `SetClipboardData`, there was another, but I can't remember). I don't know if things really go awry when you don't, though, but best to follow the documentation.

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.  It would be astonishing if there were any circumstances under which the arguments to CreateProcess needed to be preserved past the end of the call.

Comment: How could this "useful information" be used? Without details and evidence, especially as it flies in the face of all other evidence, it feels like FUD.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: an ordinary example of needing to preserve, for createprocess, is when you create a pipe to the new process' input. in windows closing the source end can cause an error instead of eof in the reading process. this is a bug in the foundations of windows and it's quite ordinary (although not what i was talking about). and neither is there anything extraordinary about createprocess having undocumented functionality. there's tons of it, google it. thus your claim that either is extraordinary is just an emotional labeling argument. it is the ordinary way of things in windows.

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges.  "Having to keep a kernel object alive" and "having to keep a memory buffer alive" are very different things.  (And I'd have to see repro code to be sure, but that doesn't sound like a bug to me.)  But if all you meant by your claim is that "if you don't follow the documentation, it might not work" ... well, that's absolutely true, but don't you think it goes without saying?

Comment: No comment.  I will add that it would still be surprising (perhaps not *extraordinarily* surprising, depending on your tolerance for surprise, but at least *unusually* surprising) if CreateProcess had any undocumented functionality that required you to provide a buffer which had to remain valid after return from the call.  (NtCreateProcess would be a different matter, however; any chance you're confusing the two?)